# Vaadin: Sub window

Tags: vaadin, custom-component

I'm trying to use a sub window but either the components I try to put in it show up in the "mainwindow" or I receive a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. I'll show you both cases. I'd like to place a HorizontalLayout in the sub window when I need to put in some real components and not just a Label and a Button.

```
public class SubWindow extends CustomComponent {

    Window mainWindow;  // Reference to main window
    Window myWindow;    // The window to be opened

    public SubWindow(Window main) {
        mainWindow = main;
        createWindow();
    }

    public void createWindow() {
        myWindow = new Window("My Dialog");

        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();

        // Add the window inside the main window. 
        mainWindow.addWindow(myWindow);

        layout.addComponent(new Label("A label"));
        layout.addComponent(new Button("Ok"));

        // The composition root MUST be set
        setCompositionRoot(layout);

        myWindow.addComponent(layout);
    } 
}
```

When I run this and open a new sub window using

```
window = new Window("Title");
setMainWindow(window);
window.addComponent(new SubWindow(window));
```

I get

SEVERE: Terminal error:

com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod$MethodException

Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:164)

...

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.vaadin.ui.CustomComponent.removeComponent(CustomComponent.java:248)
    at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponentContainer.addComponent(AbstractComponentContainer.java:207)

...

On the other hand, if I switch place between setCompositionRoot(layout) and myWindow.addComponent(layout), the Label and the Button just end up in the main window instead of the newly created sub window.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i suggest that you extend Window directly than go through a CustomLayout. A layout can't contain a window - it goes the other way around.

Change

- `public class SubWindow extends CustomComponent` to `public class SubWindow extends Window`
- `myWindow = new Window("My Dialog");` to `setCaption("My Dialog");`
- and

  ```
  // The composition root MUST be set
  setCompositionRoot(layout);

  myWindow.addComponent(layout);
  ```

  to `setContent(layout);`

That is the standard way of creating a subwindow, exactly the same way you create the main window. I would also move the `mainWindow.addWindow(myWindow);` outside of the class and not pass the mainwindow object to the subwindow, because that is not really the part of the subwindow object.

Comment: Thanks for the response, now it works like a charm. For people with the same kind of problem, here's a good tutorial on [Sub windows](http://vaadin.com/tutorial/-/chapter/skeleton.subwindows.html)